# flipping horizontally select box using css, jquery or smth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I think that it's really crazy question but anyway I want to know if maybe there is any chance to flip select box horizontally using css, jquery or smth...  Text itself remains untouched but the select box must be flipped.

[image]

Comment: Like in photoshop flip horizontal. I want the selector menu to be on the left side of select box, not on the right side.

Comment: I have no idea what the selector menu is; can you post an image to show what you've currently got, and what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some basic CSS will do the trick. It's safe to use too with solid browser support as this is usually used for languages that display "right-to-left".

```
select { direction:rtl; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really thought that it was impossible :) Will mark your answer accepted cause it's edited well.

Comment: I thought about this, but wasn't adventurous enough to give it a try... I figured it'd just reverse the text. This is awesome +1

Answer (score 4):

`direction: rtl` is the closest you can get while still using the native `select` element.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/epQFW/

Comment: I thought about this, but wasn't adventurous enough to give it a try... I figured it'd just reverse the text. This is awesome +1